# Position a Table Row in the Center of my Window using SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have a large table created with Java SWT which I can sort columnwise in various ways. But whenever I sort a column, the table starts displaying the 1st row and I could not find a way to move the table to display a specific row, e.g. the last selected row.

Any idea is appreciated!
Gerald

Comment: `Table.showItem` makes an item visible (but may not be centred). `Table.setTopItem` sets the item at the top of  the window. `Table.setSelection` should also make the selection visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Table.setTopIndex" to set the row shown at the top of the table window. So to centre a row you might use something like:

```
static void showCentredRow(Table table, int rowToShow)
{
  Rectangle clientArea = table.getClientArea();
  int itemHeight = table.getItemHeight();
  int visibleRows = clientArea.height / itemHeight;

  int topRow = Math.max(rowToShow - (visibleRows / 2), 0);
 
  table.setTopIndex(topRow);
}
```